# Recall a function

Tags: java, android

I'm performing a check of internet access in a program. I'd like to do a function to that cause this checking need to often happens... But my original function have to return while it because the screen need to refresh. This is what I have:

```
    public void isOnline(Runnable Rcallback, Ccallback) {

         ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         boolean checkState = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();

         if(checkState) {
             isOnline = true;
            if(Rcallback != null) Rcallback.run();
            if(Ccallback != null) set;}
         else {
             isOnline = false;
             Toast.makeText(gMain.this, R.string.nointernet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Handler reTry = new Handler();
                reTry.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    isOnline(callback) ;
                }
            },3000);
         }



        }
```

My really problem is in Ccallback that it's a function to call back when the program turns online. I don't know how to declare a function as a "variable". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup a listener using the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). This will allow you to tell anyone marked as a listener (likely your UI) that you have done *something*. In this case, *something* is connected.

One thing to keep in mind while doing this is to ensure that while doing things on the UI, you are on the Event Thread.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've no time now to try that, but I'll do it tomorow and post the result later.